# ASP.NET: Exposing same core functionality as SOAP _and_ REST interfaces

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, soap

We need to support both SOAP as well as REST interfaces into what is effectively the same function call. I understand SOAP is a protocol while REST is an architecture style, but I'm also sure web service developers know what I'm talking about; so lets not get distracted by the pedantic details. Also, I'd request avoiding a SOAP ***versus*** REST  debate - we need ***both*** for business needs across different customers. The platform is ASP.NET 4.0.

***REST:***

I'm using WCF and essentially inputData is consumed by FunctionA to produce OutputData. I've got the abstract interface defined via the [ServiceContract] and the actual service logic exposed via the [WebInvoke] keyword. i.e.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "funcA", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public OutputType FunctionA(InputType inputData)
```

***SOAP***

For the SOAP interface, I essentially need the same inputData going into the same FunctionA() which spits out the same OutputData (of type OutputType). Of course, these will be wrapped inside SOAP envelopes etc.

So my question is: How can I leverage the framework so that supporting a SOAP interface into the same functionality can be done with minimal custom code?

Answer (score 1):

Find my service below that provides support for both SOAP and REST

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISampleService
{
    [WebGet]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Welcome to server";
    }
}
```

My web.config would have the following

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="XMLService.SampleService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" name="SampleService" contract="XMLService.ISampleService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="XMLService.ISampleService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">          
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now the URL for your service would look like as follows:

REST --> http://localhost/SampleApp/SampleService.svc/GetData

SOAP --> http://localhost/SampleApp/SampleService.svc

If you want the REST url to be clean i.e. not have .svc in it then you can follow the WebAPI approach where you register your route in Global.asax and removed the endpoint from the config. You can perform tha same for your POST operation. Also make sure that if you are passing in complex types you need to let the service know if the types as shown below

```
[KnownType(typeof(SampleItem))]
```

The above attribute needs to be placed on the class implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

One of the projects I'm working on has this exact functionality.

Our WCF service is multi tired

- Data Access Layer
- Business Logic Layer
- Service Layer

The Service Layer has 2 End Points

- SOAP
- Rest

The End Points are very thin and basically consume methods from the BLL. So taking your example, Function A would be defined in the Business Logic Layer, where all the work would be done. Each of your Endpoints Would also have FunctionA which calls FunctionA from the BLL.

The Visual Studio Solution for this consists of a project for each of the BLL and DAL layers and a project for each of the end points. There are also a couple of other projects for unit tests etc

Comment: Great! Any C# code on how I've consume FunctionA() from a SOAP endpoint as well as define a SOAP endpoint? Sorry, more familiar with REST myself...

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options:
Create a SOAP Service and a REST Service. The Endpoint of each calsl a shared class (so there is no code duplication, eg:

```
//SOAP endpoint
[webmethod]
public void DoSomething(int id)
{
   myClass.MethodThatActuallyDoesTheWork(id);
}

//in another service we have the REST methods
//REST endpoint
public void DoSomething(int id)
{
   myClass.MethodThatActuallyDoesTheWork(id);
}
```

OR (my prefered method)

Install the [WCFWebAPI](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) via Nuget (or whatever) as this allows [content negotioation](http://blog.malevy.net/2011/06/messin-with-wcf-web-api-part-ii-content.html) in that you write one method in your service. If THE CLIENT specifies Accept: application/xml then they get XML returned, if the client specifies Accept: application/json then they get JSON back.
I am not sure if this generates a WSDL though - if your using soap 'cos you want XML then this is a good method. If you need a WSDL then two services might be better.

Food for thought anyway. Hope this helps.

If you need to test a WSDL based XML service the WCFTestClient is pretty handy.
The WCFWebApi actually generates test/help pages for you too. It's great.